# display posts of custom post type with custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, loop

I have created a custom post type **'CPT_A'** with CPT UI plugin. I have also created custom taxonomy **'Category_A'** and **'Category_B'** for **'CPT_A'**. I have Posts **'Post_A', 'Post_B', 'Post_C', 'Post_D', 'Post_E'** for **'CPT_A'** and assigned **'Post_A', 'Post_B', 'Post_C'** them to custom taxonomy **'Category_A'** and **'Post_D', 'Post_E'** to category **'Category_B'**.

I have created archive page **'archive-CPT_A.php'** to display all posts of **'CPT_A'** post type. and WP archive.php handles posts listings for all Categories of the **'CPT_A'** Posts. And there is **'single-CPT_A.php'** to display contents of single **'CPT_A'** Post.

Now, What I am trying to do is I have created a sidebar and trying to display related posts of **'CPT_A'** in sidebar. If the post is from 'Category_A' it should display other posts from same category and if the post is from 'Category_B' it should display other posts from 'Category_B' So I used this code:

```
<?php
    $cats = get_terms('CPT_A');

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'CPT_A',
        'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'cat'     => $cats[0]->term_id,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>  

<?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>   

<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

But it's displaying hiding current post from list (which is correct) but also displaying other posts from 'Category_B' too. After some research I tried this code:

```
<?php

    $cats = get_terms('tour_category');

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'tour_package',
        'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'cat'     => $cats[0]->term_id,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tour_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            )
            )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>  

<?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>   

<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

But it's displaying nothing for me.

What is the best way to do this? I didn't find any suitable tutorial for me so posting this question here.

Comment: `cat` is not a general taxonomy query var, it is specifically for the built-in `category` taxonomy, and won't work with a custom taxonomy. In your second code block, you use `$custom_term`, but you never give it a value.

Comment: oh. it's because I am just giving it a try. Can you suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "get_the_terms" to get the terms related to the post instead of "get_terms", here is a quick suggestion (not tested)

```
    $args=array(  
        'post_type'=>'tour_package',                 
        'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID()),
        'posts_per_page'=> 5, 
        'caller_get_posts'=>1,//handle sticky post but not in first
    ); 

    $categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(),'tour_category' );

    if ($categories)
            {   
                $category_ids = array();         
                foreach($categories as $individual_category){
                   $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id; 
                }
                if(!empty($category_ids))
                {

                    $args['tax_query']= array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'tour_category',
                            'field'    => 'term_id',
                            'terms'    => $category_ids,
                        ),
                    );
                }
            }
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: nothing displayed. I wonder where did $cat come from in this code:
 $args['tax_query']= array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => $cat,
                            'field'    => 'term_id',
                            'terms'    => $category_ids,
                        ),
                    );

Comment: Sorry i edited my answer

Comment: Nothing displayed.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. It was my mistake. Now it's displaying.

Comment: Glad if it works :)

Comment: Yes. It's working. Thanks. but can you suggest me how can I display posts from same category if I visit a category of 'CPT_A' ?

Comment: You need to have a taxonomy template I think, but it is another question in my opinion.

Comment: I have archive-tour_category.php already. should I code it there?

Comment: Personalty I would try a taxonomy-tour_category.php